# AngularJS POST request not returning a response when sessions are used

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I am making a POST request in angular to an API that returns a JSON object. Everything was working perfectly until I added express.sessions to the mix. Now, the POST request still gives a 200 status, but doesn't return anything for 2 minutes (when it times out). The API gets called successfully and the behavior on the backend is all normal, but I can't retrieve the response from the server. In fact, it doesn't even call the .error() function. It just times out without doing anything.

The strangest part: when I click the link that makes the POST request a second time (immediately following the first), the request and response execute exactly as expected and nothing is wrong. The first request always times out.

When I remove express.sessions, everything works as expected as well.

I am using Express on Node, AngularJS on the frontend.

Here's the code for the POST request:

Request being made. This is within an Angular controller. (Behavior: Nothing gets logged. It doesn't reach success() or error() but times out after 2min):

```
  $http.post('/api/add_highlight', newHighlight).
    success(function(id){
      console.log('response from server: ' + id)
    }).
    error(function(id){
      console.log('server response failed')
    })
```

API (Behavior: Successfully saves entry into database. Console logs all show success and behavior is normal on the backend.):

```
exports.add_highlight = function(req, res) {
  console.log('API has received request to add highlight')
      var hl = new models.highlights ({
        start: req.body.start
        , end: req.body.end
        , contents: req.body.contents
      })
      console.log(hl._id)
      hl.save(function(err){
        if (!err) {
          console.log('successfully saved highlight to mongo.')
          res.json(hl._id)
        }
        res.send('failed')
      })
};
```

app.js (When the second line is commented out, everything behaves as expected):

```
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({store: new RedisStore(), secret: '[...]'}));
```

Please let me know if you have encountered something similar before or have any ideas.

I highly suspect it's an issue with my usage of Angular, because another POST request from an example works perfectly fine. But I do suspect it also has something to do with how I'm supposed to work with sessions in Angular, because when I comment out the session line in app.js, everything works fine too.

Thanks!

Comment: Wonder if it's an error that isn't being handled or error middleware returning 200 when it should be something else. Do you have any custom error middleware in place? Also does it just return 200 without any data? Chrome dev tools or firebug could help debugging this.

Comment: Thanks Pickels! There is a little bit of error middleware, but when I comment it out, nothing gets solved. It just returns 200, but with no response (data). Yep, been using Chrome dev tools to help debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Got it- it was very silly. I didn't return my res.json and res.send